# No puedo hacer click en un link con phantom-node

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Estoy haciendo `scraping` del sitio [tematika.com](http://www.tematika.com) para poder crearme una base de libros. El problema es que necesito ir pasando de página pero no puedo, entonces siempre obtengo los mismos libros. Creo que con el código lo van a entender mejor.

```
const phantom = require("phantom");
const cheerio = require("cheerio");

let _instance, _page;
let _books = [];

phantom.create().then(instance => {
 _instance = instance;
 return _instance.createPage();
}).then(page => {
 _page = page;
 return _page.open('http://www.tematika.com/catalogo/libros/arte__arquitectura_y_diseno--9.htm');
}).then(status => {
 console.log(status);
 return _page.property('content')
}).then(html => {
 //Transformo el html en objeto para manipularlo con cheerio
 let $ = cheerio.load(html);

 //Obtengo todos los libros y los paso a un array para recorrerlos y extraer la info que busco
 let books = $('.Gcentro').find('.moduleproductob').toArray();

 //Como siempre hay 10 paginas hago un for que itere 10 veces
 for(let i=0;i<10;i++){
 books.forEach(book => {
   let _book = {};
   _book.imageMin = $(book).find('.Gimagesproductos').attr('src');
   _book.linkBook = $(book).find('.FProductos').attr('href');
   _books.push(_book);
 });

 //En esta parte lo que yo busco es hacer click en el boton siguiente de la pagina y es lo que no me esta funcionando
//Lo que termina pasando es que nunca pasa de pagina. Entonces siempre me trae la info de los mismo 10 libros.
 _page.evaluate(function() {
   var evObj = document.createEvent('Events');
   evObj.initEvent('click', true, false);
   document.getElementById('catalogNext').dispatchEvent(evObj);
 });
}
console.log(_books);
 _page.close();
 _instance.exit();
}).catch(e => console.log(e));
```

Lo que yo necesito es poder ir haciendo `click` en siguiente y poder traerme los libros que va mostrando. Si no es con `phantom-node` y `cheerio` puede ser con otra herramienta, lo unico que necesito es que funcione en `node`.